# Python - How Can I Extract the List Column Label & Value & Transpose In Respect to Unique ID

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, etl

**Below is the data frame i'm working with:**

```js
Row  |ID   | List
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |45   | [{u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Forum Thread Size'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Unique Commenters'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Likes and Votes'}]
2    |76   | [{u'value': u'1', u'label': u'Forum Thread Size'}, {u'value': u'1', u'label': u'Unique Commenters'}, {u'value': u'1', u'label': u'Engagement'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Likes and Votes'}]
3    |99   | []
4    |83   | [{u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Forum Thread Size'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Unique Commenters'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Likes and Votes'}]
5    |80   | []
```

I would like the data to look like this after the transformation, in a pandas data frame:

```js
Row |ID |Forum Thread Size |Unique Commenters |Engagement |Likes and Votes
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |45 |0                 |0          |               |0
2 |76 |1                 |1                 |1         |0
3 |99 |   |                       |               |
4 |83 |0                 |0          |               |0
5 |80 |   |                       |               |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to loop through the `List` column, and convert each list to a `pandas.Series` object with the `label` as the index; This will result in a data frame with the `label` as the column headers, and then you can `concat` with the remaining columns of the data frame to get what you need:

```
df1 = pd.concat([
    df.drop('List', 1), 
    df.List.apply(lambda lst: pd.Series({
       d['label']: d['value'] for d in lst
    }))
], axis=1)
​
df1
# Row   ID  Engagement   Forum Thread Size   Likes and Votes    Unique Commenters
#0  1   45        NaN                    0                 0                    0
#1  2   76          1                    1                 0                    1
#2  3   99        NaN                  NaN               NaN                  NaN
#3  4   83        NaN                    0                 0                    0
#4  5   80        NaN                  NaN               NaN                  NaN
```

Comment: nice and succinct+1

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the help! I can now finish my ETL automation

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df1=df.set_index(['Row','ID']).List.apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
df1.pivot_table(index=['Row','ID'], columns='label', values='value',aggfunc=np.sum).merge(df[['Row','ID']],left_index=True,right_on=['Row','ID'],how='right')

Out[334]: 
  Engagement Forum Thread Size Likes and Votes Unique Commenters  Row  ID
0       None                 0               0                 0    1   1
1          1                 1               0                 1    2   2
2        NaN               NaN             NaN               NaN    3   3
```

Data Input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Row':[1,2,3],'ID':[1,2,3], 'List':[[{u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Forum Thread Size'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Unique Commenters'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Likes and Votes'}], [{u'value': u'1', u'label': u'Forum Thread Size'}, {u'value': u'1', u'label': u'Unique Commenters'}, {u'value': u'1', u'label': u'Engagement'}, {u'value': u'0', u'label': u'Likes and Votes'}],[]]})
```